# Is Robocop immortal?

Tags: cyborg, robocop, robocop-1987

He's half man and half machine so he's gotta have a living flesh still in him. But considering he didn't age as time goes by later on in the series. Is he technically immortal then?

Comment: Are you assuming that machines are immortal? Can you name three complex machines that have continued to function longer than a human life span?

Comment: @Lexible I don't think your comment addresses the question.  Machine parts can be changed, upgraded, and fixed.  If they are all that is necessary to keep Robocop alive and well, then he could very well survive indefinitely by replacing or repairing them.

Comment: That's fair-ish, @MishaR ... still, I think that the "immortality" of machines is still worth questioning.

Answer (score 3):

Of course he is not immortal.  Robocop's body did indeed contain a significant amount of organic material—such as his brain (although not his arm, even though they could have kept it).  The unusual environment could certainly change how his organic flesh appeared to age, but the neurons making up his brain simply would not last forever.  Eventually, they would succumb (perhaps to Alzheimer's Disease, if nothing else), and he would die.

Comment: Given how they can interface with his brain for accessing of memories, maybe in-universe they could eventually download his "soul" into a computer